# Preset input for Unit tests in Python 3

Tags: python, unit-testing, io, mocking, stubbing

Was trying to solve an online coding problem in Python, and the I/O required for the submission is simple `input()` and `print()`.  Since I'm lazy and don't want to replace the I/O with method parameters in order to run unit tests, how would I create a unit test that allowed me to substitute a preset string as the input?  For instance:

```
class Test(TestCase):
    __init__(self):
        self.input = *arbitrary input*
    def test(self):
        c = Class_Being_Tested()
        c.main()
        ...make self.input the required input for c.main()
        ...test output of c.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of mock.patch() to patch the calls to any object. In this case that means patching `input()`. You can read more about it in the docs: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html In your example:

```
import mock
class Test(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('builtin.input')
    def test_input(self, input_mock):
        input_mock.return_value = 'arbitrary string'
        c = Class_Being_Tested()
        c.main()
        assert c.print_method.called_with('arbitrary string') #test that the method using the return value of input is being called with the proper argument
```

Notice that if you are using pytest you could also create a fixture and automatically use it with `autouse`. Check an example here: http://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-fixtures-nuts-bolts/#autouse